# load swf with if statement in .as file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is my situation.  I am currently in school and have googled, searched stack, and various other sites.  I am creating a game for this course I have and am creating each portion in it's own SWF/FLA file.  My problem is arising with making a call to the game over swf.

Below is the code

```
                //Variable for loading Game Over
            var over_Loader:Loader = new Loader()
            var over_Url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("game_over.swf")

            //hit testing with the hero
            if(hitTestObject(_root.hero))
            {
                //losing the game
                _root.gameOver = true;
            }
            //Load SWF Game Over
            if(gameOver == true)
            {
                addChild(over_Loader);
                over_Loader.load(over_Url);
            }
```

I made sure that the imports needed are loaded at the top of the .as file and just to be sure I made sure the imports were in the both swf files even went so far as to declare the variables in all 3 as well.

If I add _root to the addChild and overLoader.load the game starts out with the Game Over screen displaying but when the game is truly over the hero still moves but no longer fires and no enemies drop from the top.  I get no display of the of the Game Over screen but no errors either to trace down.

So I guess my question is to sum it all up is there a way to make a call to load this SWF (game_over.swf) from the gameOver conditional or is this a command that can only be initiated via a button click event?  If that is the case how would one recommend to get this Game Over screen to appear?

Thanks in advance for your help and if anyone wants the files you can find them all here in the link below
[Files for the Game Large in Size](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5x6Yds5Dp22OGV2SDd3UFRhWEE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try explaining yourself more clearly, and show the concrete problem you are experiencing.

Comment: My problem I am having is in the last section where it says Load SWF Game Over there is a conditional that checks for the game to be over.  If the game is over I ask it to load the over_url.  It does not do this.  This coding is located in the enemies.as file   When I start the game it starts with the game_over.swf displayed instead of the game.  Is there not a way to call an external swf file without a user interaction such as a button click?  Apparently the conditional statement is not loading properly to display the Game Over file.

Comment: May I ask why you are creating each portion in a separate SWF?

Comment: Due to some other problems I have encountered I found this an easier way for me to do it.  I was getting errors with assets when I was trying to make calls to other frames by name.  For example, on the 'Game Over' frame I would get errors with my mcHero asset not existing.  It wouldn't break the game but it was causing problems with an overload of enemies if the player would click restart.